# Android animation-list oneshot not read from xml in Marshmallow

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am loading an animation into an image view and loading the AnimationDrawable like so:

Activity call

```
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = 
    (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.my_animation);
mAnimationImageView.setBackground(animationDrawable);
```

my_animation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_animation_00" android:duration="@integer/100" />
        ...
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_animation_10" android:duration="@integer/100" />
</animation-list>
```

The oneshot is read and applied on my test devices except for the Nexus 5x that is running Marshmallow. On that device the animation repeats indefinitely. Since one shot is false by default in the AnimationState I'm guessing it's not being read.

I can set the one shot in code to fix it:

```
mAnimationDrawable.setOneShot(true);
```

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: Have you tried using the `NineOldDroids` library? Chances are, when using it the animation problem won't happen.

Comment: Why import a whole library when I can fix it with .setOneShot(true)?

Comment: Because it's backwards compatible back to Cupcake.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to really be any bug here. This might have been an artifact of running Android Studio 2.0 Preview 7. The code is working fine now.

> Uh, we had a slight ide malfunction, but uh... everything's perfectly all right now. We're fine. We're all fine here now, thank you. How are you?